# Get EC2 CPU utilization using AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I need to create a AWS Lambda function in JAVA to print the EC2 instance's CPU Utilisation. How to get the CPU utilization of EC2 instance using AWS JAVA SDK.

Comment: Why do you wish to use Lambda to do this? What will trigger the Lambda function, and what do you mean by "print"?

Comment: The lambda will be triggered timely(rate(1 min)). Print to the logs.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Amazon CloudWatch maintains a history, so it would be simpler to retrieve the data from there, rather than in your own "logs".

Answer (score 3):

**Amazon CloudWatch** maintains metrics about every Amazon EC2 instance, including CPU Utilization.

By default, metrics are collected at 5-minute intervals at no charge. You can enable **detailed monitoring** for an instance, which will collect metrics at 1-minute intervals. Additional charges apply.

You can obtain the metrics via a call to Amazon CloudWatch. Use the [`getMetricData()` function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html#getMetricData-com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.GetMetricDataRequest-).

Note that you actually request a calculated value over a period of time, such as "Average CPU for the previous 5 minutes".

Comment: How to specify the EC2 instance in the CloudWatchClient object. I need to get the specific ec2 instance's CPU usage. Or is there any similar method in the Ec2Client class.

Comment: You can specify it as a parameter to `getMetricData()`. You might want to experiment by calling it via [get-metric-data — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html) since it is easier to experiment. Then, once you understand the required parameters, put it into your Java code. See: [Get Statistics for a Specific Instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/US_SingleMetricPerInstance.html)